# PermissionError Forbidden reading from s3 bucket from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr, aws-policies

So the problem I'm encountering is that I built a docker image that will run an etl pipeline. When I run the image locally it works fine but when I deploy my image to ECR on AWS and I run my lambda function that uses this image it returns a PermissionError Forbidden. Here is the full stacktrace.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Forbidden",
  "errorType": "PermissionError",
  "requestId": "ed12c997-d1f7-4cba-8eaf-66b88643271c",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 10, in handler\n    main(now)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/scraper_backend/jobs/__init__.py\", line 15, in main\n    df = transform.update_file(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/scraper_backend/jobs/transform.py\", line 24, in update_file\n    df = read_file(path)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/scraper_backend/jobs/transform.py\", line 15, in read_file\n    dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(f\"s3://{bucket}/{key}\", filesystem=fs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py\", line 1763, in __new__\n    return _ParquetDatasetV2(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet/core.py\", line 2452, in __init__\n    finfo = filesystem.get_file_info(path_or_paths)\n",
    "  File \"pyarrow/_fs.pyx\", line 571, in pyarrow._fs.FileSystem.get_file_info\n",
    "  File \"pyarrow/error.pxi\", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status\n",
    "  File \"pyarrow/_fs.pyx\", line 1490, in pyarrow._fs._cb_get_file_info\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/fs.py\", line 330, in get_file_info\n    info = self.fs.info(path)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py\", line 115, in wrapper\n    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py\", line 100, in sync\n    raise return_result\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py\", line 55, in _runner\n    result[0] = await coro\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3fs/core.py\", line 1248, in _info\n    out = await self._call_s3(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3fs/core.py\", line 348, in _call_s3\n    return await _error_wrapper(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3fs/core.py\", line 140, in _error_wrapper\n    raise err\n"
  ]
}
```

So I firstly went to IAM console to change my permissions and the policy looks like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also just tried this policy but this also didn't seem to fix my permission forbidden error

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure how long it takes for a policy to be in effect so maybe that is the problem, but it has been like 15-20 minutes so I doubt that that will be the problem. So if anyone has any idea what the problem could be any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your bucket?

Comment: I used 2 different names here but that because i just copy pasted the example in my policy I put the real name of my bucket and I am sure that that is not wrong

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or the code of your IAM Policy? Is this policy attached to the lambda function?

Comment: Hey @matheusopedro, thank you for looking into the problem I was encountering. As you mentioned in your message, this policy was not attached to my lambda function which was my problem.

Comment: Glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone encountering this permission forbidden error. This is likely becuase your lambda function has no rights to access your s3 bucket. What you need to do? See my other question and answer in this post [Is it possible to give parameters to ECR image on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041868/is-it-possible-to-give-parameters-to-ecr-image-on-aws) .

### EDIT:

Like mentioned in the comments this is what you need to to as reffered in the link above. You just need to attach the policy to access your s3 bucket to your execution role on your lambda function.
Your IAM policy could look like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is depending on the rights you want to give to your s3 bucket (this one gives all rights to all files in my bucket). Now if your lambda function needs access to your s3 bucket you need to add this policy to the execution role of your lambda function. You do this by going to your lambda function and find your execution role. Then in the IAM center go to your policy that you created (the policy above) and attach it to your execution role. I hope everyone who encounters this error can fix it like this.

Comment: It might be more benefitial for other users if you copy the most relevant parts of your other answer directly here. The other post can be deleted and we would loose your solution.